# React bootstrap modal not animating

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Why the modal isn't animating for this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/7klz2zl8mx

Modal with animation: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals-live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have't included the required css in the project. Add this css link in the `External Resources` section of your project https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css.
This is outlined in `react-bootstrap` [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html)

[image]